# Can you "draw to" anything but a close?

Tags: expressions

Today, *draw* means mostly “sketch”, but it used to mean “pull”, and it still does, figuratively, as in “draw a crowd”, “draw a card”, or “draw water” In the literal sense of pulling, it has mostly been supplanted by its parent, *drag*, except in fixed phrases like "horse-drawn wagon".

Occasionally, you see it used intransitively, "draw near" or "draw nigh", but those are pretty rare.

I'm curious about the intransitive use "draw to a close" (or "a finish" or "an end", frequently with an adjective).  Events don't draw to their start, or even the middle.

Is there anything else you can draw *to*, in this temporal sense?

Comment: Minor niggle: _drag_ isn’t the ‘parent’ of _draw_. _Draw_ is the inherited, English form (with OE /ɡ/ after a back vowel regularly yielding [ɣ] > [ɣʷ] > [w]), while _drag_ first appears several hundred years later and is either borrowed from or influenced by the Old Norse verb (and/or perhaps a northern dialect form), where the velar /ɡ/ was maintained.

Comment: @Keepthesemind -- You mean _n_ as a direct object? "I am going to draw this conversation to a close"?  I have heard that too, but it is an ordinary transitive use, no different from "draw a curtain" or "draw a blank".  I am curious about intransitive uses: "The conversation drew to a close".

Comment: @Malvolio you mean you want other words that can replace "close" in "draw to a close"?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet -- you mean, the Norse would say "drag", which led the English to saying "draw", but then the English started saying "drag" too?  That's interesting. I wonder how often that happened, that a word was effectively imported twice.

Comment: My point is that perhaps "draw to a close" originally/properly is/was "drawn to a close" (only).

Comment: @NVZ -- I don't know about "replace", because the meaning of the sentence would be different, but yes, I want a meaningful and idiomatic sentence of the form, "The _something_ drew to a _something else_." where the something else is neither a close nor an inside straight.

Comment: @Malvolio No, _draw_ is the original English word. It wasn’t imported from anywhere—it’s inherited all the way back to Proto-Indo-European. In Old English, it was _dragan_. That /ɡ/ in the middle there, though, regularly became a /w/ eventually (and the _-an_ ending for the infinitive was lost), so it became _draw_. Old Norse had a verb that was cognate to _draw_, which in ON was _draga_, almost identical. But there was no such /ɡ/ > /w/ change in ON, so when the Norse ruled Britain and their language heavily influenced English, there was a slightly different, but obviously easily →

Comment: @Keepthesemind -- interesting point, but how could an evening _be_ drawn to a close?  A conversation or an argument, sure, even a party, those are subject to the will of men, but periods of time draw to their ends, though no one can drag them anywhere.

Comment: I found some from Google Ngrams, but the link is too long to be pasted here. Try yourself `draw to a *`. I get _draw to a close, conclusion, head, point, crisis, certain, scale, period, plea_

Comment: → recognisable word that could be borrowed. So easily recognisable, in fact, that it might not even really have been a borrowing, but more a case of “They say it slightly differently from us, so we’ll just consider their version an alternative pronunciation”, and then they ended up with two near-identical verbs.

Comment: @NVZ -- Drawing to a _head_!  That's a good one.  You should make it an answer!

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet -- alternate pronunciation was exactly what I was considering _dragan_.

Comment: I've been told that it's usually a bad idea to draw to an inside straight.

Answer (score 3):

***To draw to a head*** — [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/To+draw+to+a+head)

> (Med.) To begin to suppurate; to ripen, as a boil.
>   To ripen, to approach the time for action; as, *the plot draws to a head*

I found this from [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=draw%20to%20a%20*&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cdraw%20to%20a%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bdraw%20to%20a%20close%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdraw%20to%20a%20conclusion%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdraw%20to%20a%20head%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdraw%20to%20a%20point%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdraw%20to%20a%20crisis%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdraw%20to%20a%20certain%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdraw%20to%20a%20scale%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdraw%20to%20a%20Conclusion%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdraw%20to%20a%20period%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdraw%20to%20a%20plea%3B%2Cc0). I get *draw to a close, conclusion, head, point, crisis, certain, scale, period, plea*. Most of those do not appear to be idiomatic, or they do not work the same way as "draw to a close" does.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can explore these types of question at the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/). They have a British corpus there too.

Here are the first ten results from the American one for the query, `[draw] to a *` :

```
1        DREW TO A CLOSE       150 
2        DRAWING TO A CLOSE    149 
3        DRAWS TO A CLOSE      115 
4        DRAW TO A CLOSE        33  
5        DRAWN TO A CLOSE        9   
6        DREW TO A HALT          9   
7        DRAWN TO A PARTICULAR   8   
8        DRAWN TO A WOMAN        6   
9        DREW TO A STOP          6   
10       DRAWN TO A MORE         5
```

Comment: That's the weakness of automated searches.  All the top examples are either variants of "draw to a close" or fragments of a passive-voice sentence like "x is drawn to y".